# Having trouble with my modal table rows not being responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, responsive

My modal is being responsive just fine but my rows either use a scroll bar or they overflow out of the modal. I cant get them to be responsive and I have tried a couple of ways but just not sure if I need to make my table in my modal a datatable or if I can just leave it be. I have tried it a couple ways like i said with a DT and without inside.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" title="Cancelled Items" aria-labelledby="dialog-confirmLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-sm" role="document" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
```

Comment: have you tried making your table responsive with class table-responsive? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp

Comment: Yeah that was my first try since it seemed like the easiest option and it did nothing.

Comment: You're wanting to view the entire width of the table no matter how small the modal gets? I don't think that's possible, according to Bootstrap, `table-responsive` just makes the table `scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px).` I would think this is the same for `modal-sm` which is by default set to 300px. http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/GjVeZr

Answer (score 0):

your data table will remain in

```
 <div class="modal body">
```

so give style on it if it overflows :

```
 <div class="modal body" style="overflow:hidden">
```

also you can do that with

```
    <div class="row " style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow:hidden">
```

if you want the scroll then,

```
   overflow-x:scroll
   overflow-y:scroll
```

Try if it helps,

Thanks

Comment: Still getting the same outcome with this. The row just is getting cut off instead of collapsing down like the main datatable does.

Comment: can you put snapshot of it? also  class="table table-striped" do overflow:hidden. else ( overflow:scroll ) hoping for best :-)